# How to remove id from url in laravel

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, url, routes

I am trying to remove id from the url. My urls's are something like this,

```
https://www.example.com/p/29/web-test
```

But, I want the url like

```
https://www.example.com/p/web-test
```

And my route is,

```
Route::get('/p/{id}/{any}','TestController@dynamic_page')->name('dynamic.page');
```

I have tried several codes .htacces like

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ p/$1 [L]
```

But its not working, can anyone please help me out, I am poorly trapped in it,

Comment: Why don't you just make the Route like that: `Route::get('/p/{any}','TestController@dynamic_page')->name('dynamic.page');` and use get parameters to pass the id?

Comment: no, I can't because there is no slug in it, everything is managing through id

Comment: Try like this way `https://www.example.com/p/web-test-29`

Comment: but still, there is id in it at the end of url

Comment: If you remove the id from URL. How do you suppose to get data?

Comment: There is no logical answer to your question, just you can use slug (`unique`) in table

Comment: thats the problem, I can't remove the id, as every data is dependent on id, I am looking for a way through which I can hide the id from the url,

Comment: is it possible through ,htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Try this

Encrypt the `$id` in blade

```
{{ route('route_name', encrypt($id)) }}
```

And then decrypt id in crontroller.

```
$id = decrypt($id)
```

It will display encrypted id in URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do what you are trying to achieve because if you remove the id from the url, using a `.htaccess` file or any other redirection method, the final route will still hit Laravel at the end.

If this route does not contain the required data (in your case, the id), it will simply not work.

The only way to "hide" the id from the url while still getting it on the server side (in Laravel) would be to change it after the page has been loaded, using javascript. But to be honnest it is ugly and I strongly discourage you of doing this.

The good news is, putting the id in the url is not a bad practice. Doing what has been proposed in the comments, `https://www.example.com/p/web-test-29`, is totally fine. Also, using a unique slug could also do the job (and this time, without the id).

It's all up to you, both these methods are technically OK and SEO friendly.

*As a side note, since you mentioned it, I would advice against the use of `.htaccess` files whenever it is possible, since it'll bind your application to Apache and you might run into troubles if you want to switch to another web server later, like Nginx.*